# Removing text from a sibling

Tags: jquery

My HTML looks like this:

```
<blockquote>
  <strong class="quote-title">
    Mary wrote:
  </strong>
  <hr />The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
</blockquote>
```

I want to remove/hide the hr tag and the "quick brown fox" sentence but leave the text within strong alone.

How do I do this if strong is my current element?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("strong").next()[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "" // Or nextSibling.remove()
$("strong").next().remove()
```

This will remove the Text after the `</hr>` and the `</hr>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/PdB5G/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('blockquote').html(function(){
    return $(this).find('.quote-title')[0].outerHTML;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.quote-title').nextAll('hr').remove();
```

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/27FRU/

Comment: nice, but i think he wants to remove the string and horizontal line. After `Mary wrote:` edit: i also think that the string should be wrapped in some sort of HTML cause its currently just sitting on the page.

Comment: Oh, yes, I read that incorrectly, as @Omri Aharon suggest I thing the text will need to be wrapped in a container of some sort

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap `<hr/>...` in a `div` and then take your strong text element, and remove the sibling, like this:

```
var elem = $('.quote-title');
elem.next().remove();
```

Take a look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vjGu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the sentence in a container. For example this way:

```
<blockquote>
  <strong class="quote-title">
    Mary wrote:
  </strong>
  <div><hr />The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>
</blockquote>
```

Then you can hide it in jQuery:

```
$('.quote-title').next().hide();
```

or in css:

```
.quote-title + div { display: none; }
```